# Caveats when using Schemas in SQL Server DB

Tags: sql-server, database-design, database-schema, sql-server-2016

I last looked at Schemas (on Oracle) about 20 years ago, I know that Microsoft changed schemas in SQL Server 2005. We're now about to create a new application and I've long wanted to take another look at schemas.

We use 1 specific login to do the applications work so it has `db_owner` role and 1 specific login for running all reports so it has `data_reader` role.

I've done my research as well as poked around and wrote some scripts. This script "appears" to be all I need in order to create a schema:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [MySchema];
```

I used the `sa` user to create the schema and related tables. From there, I've been able to create tables within the schema and access them just fine from the two users.

My question is, was this very simple statement all that there is required to create a schema "correctly" and are there any specifics I should be watching out for?

We already access all db objects with the `[dbo].` schema prefix in preparation for going multi-schema.  I'm just not sure if there's something sneaky when we finally start getting into stored procedures, functions, views, indexes, foreign keys and the likes.  So far all my testing has come up roses but I'm concerned I'm missing something that's going to really beat me with a stick some ways down the line.

Comment: One question per post please.

Comment: My only feedback is some client tools don't play nice with schemas or are not schema aware. It really depends on your client tool. Last time I checked, Entity Framework was _not_ schema aware - if you had the same object name in two schemas it got confused.

Comment: All the other questions you have are basically security questions. `data_reader` is not a built in database role. If you meant `db_datareader` then even then that user mightbe explicitly granted other access. You need to check the grants on the user. In short schemas are a _good_ idea and you should use them but beforehand consider the "orthogonality" - will schemas represent business units, business processes, application modules etc.

Comment: @ Nick.McDermaid: you can use schemas with EF, but it's not great....

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use a user in role db_owner for application access, Create a user and give it data_reader/data_writer

Comment: @philipxy: I don't see how this can be broken into multiple questions as they're all directly related.  Wouldn't it be better defined as 1 TOPIC per question?  Anyway, I've reduced the discussion even though I believe it's properly defined and perfectly valid.

Comment: It's not one topic one post, it's one question per post. If you have different questions about a given situation then it's one situation with multiple questions--ie requests for multiple answers--then it's different questions/posts. There's some grey with everything, I'd say yours are different questions & answers. [ask]